# Add server to WSUS group membership using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need some idea to start this

As part of new VM build, I have to add server to a specific WSUS group based on server OS version.

[image]

So, if I have a server with OS as windows 2019, then I have to select **Project-Win2k19** under **Project-Servers**

Please let me know on this how to start on this.

Comment: `[Add-WsusComputer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/updateservices/add-wsuscomputers)` ??

Comment: @Theo: Thanks. Let me check on this. Needed something to start.. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Install-Module -Name PoshWSUS
Import-Module -Name PoshWSUS
Connect-PSWSUSServer -Verbose -WsusServer $YourWSUSserver -port 8531  
Add-PSWSUSClientToGroup -Group $RebootPolicy -Computername $servername
```

This should be the minimum needed to get you started.